$\int^{0.75}_{0.25} (f \circ g^{-1})(x) dx$
Let $f(x)= \frac{2 \cdot 10^x +10^{2x}}{1+10^x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{10^x}{1+10^x}$
What is the value of $\int^{0.75}_{0.25} (f \circ g^{-1})(x) dx$
How I solved it:
I first found $g^{-1}(x)$
Let $y=g(x) $
$y=\frac{10^x}{1+10^x}$
interchanging the variables we get
$x= \frac{10^y}{1+10^y} \implies 10^y=x+10^y \cdot x \implies (1-x)\cdot 10^y=x \implies10^y= \frac{x}{1-x} \implies y= \log_{10}(\frac{x}{1-x})=-\frac{\log(-\frac{x-1}{x})}{\log(10)}$
(Don't know which of the two final forms will be usefull so I keep them both)
so
$$(f \circ g^{-1})(x)=\frac{2 \cdot 10^{\log_{10}(\frac{x}{1-x})} +10^{2\log_{10}(\frac{x}{1-x})}}{1+10^{\log_{10}(\frac{x}{1-x})}}$$
and simplifying we get  $$\frac{2 \frac{x}{1-x}+10^{\log_{10}((\frac{x}{1-x})^2)}}{1+\frac{x}{1-x}}= \dots =\frac{2x-x^2}{1-x}$$
so we just need to evalute $$\int_{0.25}^{0.75}\frac{2x-x^2}{1-x}dx = \int_{0.25}^{0.75}\frac{2x}{1-x}-\frac{x^2}{1-x} dx = \left(\frac{1-2x+x^2}{2}-\log(|1-x|))\right\rvert^{0.75}_{0.25}=-\frac{1}{4}+ \log(3)$$
My question is , is there any substitution we can make to make this easier ? For example when we have $\int f^{-1}(x) dx $ we can let $x=f(t)$ and the integral becomes that much easier . Is there any similar "trick" we can do here, or in these types of problems?

i think this sort of problems are just case by case. if it works, no need for questioning.

In general, I do not know any results that facilitate the resolution of integrals of the kind $\int f \circ g^{-1} (x) dx$.
But, for this particular problem: yes, there is an "easy solution".
First, see that $f(x) = g(x) + 10^x$.
$$f(x) = \frac{2\cdot 10^x + 10^{2x}}{10^x+1} =\frac{10^x}{10^x+1} + \frac{10^x(10^x+1)}{10^x+1} = g(x) + 10^x$$
Notice that we can cancel $10^x+1$ from the last fraction because it $10^x+1 \neq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Manipulating $g(x)$, we have:
$$g(x) = \frac{10^x}{1+10^x} \implies 10^x = \frac{g(x)}{1-g(x)}$$
Then, plug in the two results, we have:
$$f(x) = g(x) + \frac{g(x)}{1-g(x)}$$
And, consequently
$$f(g^{-1}(x) ) = g(g^{-1}(x)) + \frac{g(g^{-1}(x))}{1-g(g^{-1}(x))} = x + \frac{x}{1-x}$$
And, your integral can be written as:
$$\int_{0.25}^{0.75} x + \frac{x}{1-x} dx$$

I think that the following step is wrong .
$$g(x) = \frac{10^x}{1+10^x} \implies 10^x = \frac{g(x)}{1+g(x)}$$
It should instead be
$$g(x) = \frac{10^x}{1+10^x} \implies 10^x = \frac{g(x)}{1-g(x)}$$

Indeed. Thanks for pointing out. I will correct.

that was a really nice observation thanks for helping , I really liked your approach

What you need is two substitutions. In fact,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int^{0.75}_{0.25} (f \circ g^{-1})(x) dx\\
&\overset{y=g^{-1}(x)}=&\int^{g^{-1}(0.75)}_{g^{-1}(0.25)} f(y)g'(y) dy\\
&\overset{t=10^y}=&\int_{10^{g^{-1}(0.25)}}^{10^{g^{-1}(0.75)}}\frac{t(2+t)}{1+t}\cdot\frac{t\ln(10)}{(1+t)^2}\cdot\frac{dt}{t\ln(10)}\\
&=&\int_{10^{g^{-1}(0.25)}}^{10^{g^{-1}(0.75)}}\frac{t(2+t)}{(1+t)^3}dt.
\end{eqnarray}$$
It is easy to see
$$ g^{-1}(x)=\log_{10}(\frac{x}{1-x}) $$
and hence
$$ 10^{g^{-1}(0.25)}=\frac{0.25}{1-0.25}=\frac13, 10^{g^{-1}(0.75)}=\frac{0.75}{1-0.75}=3. $$
So
$$\int^{0.75}_{0.25} (f \circ g^{-1})(x) dx=\int_{\frac13}^3\frac{t(2+t)}{(1+t)^3}dt=-\frac14+\ln(3). $$
